# Which direction do Coconut Wheels turn if they are destroyed?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

So I know for sure that Coconut Wheels move the direction you switch a candy, but what about when it's randomly destroyed in some way? Which direction does it activate? Is there a pattern regarding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience has shown that it's random when not done directly by the player, much like the direction of randomly generated hard candies.  I have not seen a preferred direction based on how the Coconut Wheel was destroyed.

Comment: This matches my experience.  You'll see it spin a short random amount of time, then it picks a direction.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah it doesn't seem like a pattern. I suppose it's random or something